# Is there a simple way to find the conjugacy classes of $A_n$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

For the symmetric groups $S_n$ there's a quite simple way to find all the conjugacy classes. We find partitions of $n$, that is, we write

$$n = n_1+\cdots+n_k,$$

and then for each such partition there's a conjugacy class which is the set of all permutations of the form

$$\sigma=\sigma_1\cdots\sigma_k,$$

being $\sigma_i$ one $n_i$-cycle.

Now, what about $A_n$, the alternating groups? Is there any systematic way like that to find all the conjugacy classes?

Comment: conjugacy class of Sn splits into 2 in An iff cycle type is a collection of distinct odd integers.